# Compatible OS on AMD APU Dual Core-E1-2100 with 4Gb RAM

Tags: versions

I would like to use Ubuntu on my Lenovo laptop with AMD APU Dual Core-E1-2100 and 4Gb RAM, let me know the compatible Ubuntu OS.

Comment: All Ubuntu will be compatible, but you're asking the wrong question.  Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, some have 9 months supported lives, others have 3-5 years of support (3 years for flavors, 5 for main), let alone what applications you wish to run, your tastes, etc... which all influence the best for you.  But regardless, they'll all run, like I can run all on my 2009 dell box (but some have pros that beat the cons of others for me!)

Answer (score 0):

Because the AMD E1 CPU's/APU's were very slow (I had one too), you should probably go with something like Lubuntu. And because I am Irsu and don't like to upgrade my windows and linux, I would go with 20.04 LTS.